# Nest can't resolve service dependencies when it's about a different service from a different brother

Tags: nestjs

I am kind of new in NestJS and I'm encountering a problem when I try to inject into a service from a module declare in AppModule, with another service as well declare into another module in AppModule.

Eg:

```ts
**app.module.ts**
  imports: [
    CoreModule,

    ProductsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [
    AppController,
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService,
  ],
```

```ts
**core.module.ts**

 imports: [
  ],
  controllers: [
    BrandsController,
    CategoriesController,
    ReviewsController,
  ],
  providers: [
    BrandsService,
    CategoriesService,
    ReviewsService,
  ],
  exports: [
    ReviewsService,
  ]
```

Since I need the controllers from he core.module.ts I had to inject it into app.modules.ts.

In the same time, I need some of the services and controllers from this module to inject them into products.module.ts.

```ts
**products.module.ts**

imports: [
  ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ProductsService,
  ],
  controllers: [
    ProductsController,
  ]
```

Now my problem is that I get:

**Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ProductsService (?, ReviewsService). Please make sure that the argument ProductModel at index [0] is available in the ProductModule context.**

Comment: Can you show the constructor of your `ProductService`?

Comment: The answer you provided should have been added to the question, not as an answer. Also, this does not match up with the error you've given. According to your error, your `ProductsService` should have two dependencies, but this only has one.  Do you have `MongooseModule.forFeature()` in your `ProductsModule`'s `imports` array?

Answer (score -1):

Here constructor for the products.service.ts:

````
constructor(
    @InjectModel('Product') 
    private readonly productModel: Model<IProductSchema>,
  ) { }```

I am using MongoDB and mongoose schema for collections.
````